# Dockerfile fails with install forever

Tags: dockerfile, npm-install, forever

I'm running a docker and its construction fails with this output messsage:

> docker.errors.BuilError: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install npm'
>   returned a non-zero code: 1

Dockerfile has this code:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common

RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN apt-get install npm

RUN npm install forever -g
```

Otherwise I can correctly execute the same commands just directy at command line outside docker's construction, and on Ubuntu 14:04.

Also I've runned another version of dockerfile without this commands, and it constructs dockers correctly.

Can you help me, please?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must pass the '-y' flag on install npm since it means 'yes' to apt-get prompt. If you look closely the other install commands already have it.

Comment: Thaks for the advise. But by adding -y it doesn't work neither.